# Bootstrap 4 & flex and collapsible content on full-height page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have a collapsible `div` (fixed height) on a full-height page with flex and bootstrap 4 (same issue with bootstrap 3).

The current snippet works great on Firefox but it does not work on Chrome-based browsers: the initial size of the `collapsable` is correct (`100px`), but once you collapse it, it does not resize properly (`0px` if subresizable's height is `100%`, or proportional to the available space).

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  flex-flow: column;
}

#collapsable {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

#subresizable {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

#resizable {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;

  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</header>
<body>

  <div id="resizable">
    <div id="subresizable">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsable">COLLAPSE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapsable" class="collapse in"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Bootstrap 3, I think you just need to make sure `#resizable` is `display: flex;`

```
#resizable {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/DcioXI4Xwl

In Bootstrap 4, you can just use `d-flex` util class.

---

Related question: [Show/Hide div in Bootstrap 4 while resizing height of leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324792/show-hide-div-in-bootstrap-4-while-resizing-height-of-leaflet-map/49325433)